# Decide threshold for LM to filter out ill-formed sentence

Tags: machine-learning, mathematical-statistics, natural-language, language-models

I have a corpus of sentences. This corpus contains well-formed as well as ill-formed sentences. I want to filter out ill-formed sentences from the corpus.

Ill-formed sentences are of **two types** :

1. Sentences with grammatical errors, Ex : "What are the symptom of fever ?"
2. Incoherent sentences, Ex : "How do you cure apple ?"

The first thing which I tried was Language Model. I used the perplexity scores as well LM probability to decide which ones better. In perplexity case lower the better and in LM probability case, higher the better.

But the problem I am facing with is how to decide the threshold of the value for perplexity and LM prob?

Looking at the scores seems there's a significant overlap in distribution of good and bad sentences.

I also don't have a labelled dataset, and hence I can't build a classifier where features would be LM Prob and Perplexity.

Any ideas is highly appreciated.

Comment: I think you're going to have a real hard time finding a threshold that works well for this. You need some way to normalize it. If you had a LM trained on ill-formed data and one trained on clean data you could do a threshold on the ratio between the two LMs.

Comment: The issue is I don't have ill-formed data. Do you think instead of going for just LM/perplexity score, I should use Semantic Parser etc .